# Is there a point to kicking the helmet down stairs and saving the guy?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

You can save a minion with a helmet, then you can kick his helmet back downstairs again and keep saving him. Is there a point to it besides the satisfaction torturing the little fella?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving him the third time, there will be a "reward" (not sure what that is yet) for you in the Gunegeon and you can't kick the helmet down anymore.